# Create a new object from export modules using bowserify

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify

I'm trying to use the object I've expose from the a javascript file using browserify, but I keep getting error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Here is an example:

`foo.js`:

```
var foo = function() {
  this.f1 = function(){
    console.log('function1')
  }
  this.f2 = function(){
    console.log('function2')
  }
};

module.exports = foo;
```

I'm trying to use the `foo` in the index.html.

after enter command: `browserify foo.js > bundle.js`

and include `bundle.js` to html file.

`index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
      var foo = new foo();  // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

      foo.f1();
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong with browserify? Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:** for wrong example.

original wrong example

`foo.js`:

```
var foo = {
  f1: function(){
    console.log('function1')
  },
  f2: function(){
    console.log('function2')
  }
};

module.exports = foo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
browserify foo.js --standalone foo > bundle.js
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use new, you should declare the foo class like:

```
foo = function() {
  this.f1 = function(){
    console.log('function1')
  };
  this.f2 = function(){
    console.log('function2')
  };
};

foo_obj = new foo();
foo_obj.f1();
foo_obj.f2();
```

Instead of a literal. Otherwise, simply the methods of the foo object.

```
var foo = {
  f1: function(){
    console.log('function1')
  },
  f2: function(){
    console.log('function2')
  }
};

foo.f1();
foo.f2();
```

**Update:**

Let's see, I've never used browserify, but accordingly to their [docs](http://browserify.org/), you should do something like:

foo.js

```
module.exports = function() {
  this.f1 = function(){
    console.log('function1')
  },
  this.f2 = function(){
    console.log('function2')
  }
};
```

main.js

```
var foo = require('foo');
```

Then, do:

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

And finally import bundle.js and use `new foo()` to create the object inside your script.

Comment: We worked in parallel & you bested me. I honor you with an upvote @Sergio Aristizábal

Comment: Sorry, I've made a stupid mistake. But after I've change to your answer, I still can't defined the function in `browserify`

Comment: My original code is like the one you answered. Sorry for the wrong sample.

Comment: how about `module.exports = {foo: foo};`?

Comment: @SergioAristizábal thanks for all your work! But the answer I've checked works, and I think is the best answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to instantiate an object as if it was a function, e.g.

```js
new {}; // invalid!!
new function() {}; // valid!
```

I would recommend you use either

```js
exports.foo1 = function() { console.log('foo'); }
exports.bar1 = function() { console.log('bar'); }
```

or if you really want to keep `new foo()` use:

```js
module.exports = foo;
function foo() {
    this.foo1 = function() { console.log('foo'); }
    this.bar1 = function() { console.log('bar'); }
}
```